# Excel VBA Consolidate data and delete

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that, after grabbing data from another worksheet and formatting it, should be adding together data in columns b, c, and d, when column a is a duplicate in the first row and then deleting the duplicate second row. The intention is that if two sets of data have the same identifier in the first column, I only see a total from the sets as opposed to a list.

```
Range("A3:A50").Select
Set y = Selection
For x = 1 To y.Rows.Count
If y.Cells(x, 1).Value = y.Cells(x, 2).Value Then
    a = y.Cells(x + 1, 1).Value
    a = a + y.Cells(x + 1, 2).Value
    y.Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = a
    y.Cells(x + 2, 1).Value = y.Cells(x + 2, 1).Value + y.Cells(x + 2, 2).Value
    y.Cells(x + 3, 1).Value = y.Cells(x + 3, 1).Value + y.Cells(x + 3, 2).Value
End If
If y.Cells(x, 2).Value = y.Cells(x, 1).Value Then
    y.Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
```

This is that section of code, and there is two attempts mixed in here. In the first If statement, I'm trying to use "a" as a way to store the value of the first cell in column B then adding the duplicate info from below it. The other two are trying to add the cell values directly. Neither appear to be working, and the second If isn't either, none of the duplicate data is being deleted and instead it looks like it deletes rows at random. Please let me know what I can do to improve either sections.

Comment: well, there's a lot going on here, but what sticks out the most to me is that you mention you want to add `columns b, c, and d` but in the range references you use (`.cells(...)`), you only ever specify over to column 2 (which is column b)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're attempting to do. Could you provide a sample of data (fake data if necessary) that lays out the initial condition then a sample of what you're after for your output?

Comment: Your code doesn't check if row 1 column A is the same as row row 2 column A.  `y.Cells(x, 1).Value = y.Cells(x, 2).Value` checks if row 1 column A is the same as row 1 column B.  Maybe `y.Cells(x, 1).Value = y.Cells(x+1, 1).Value`

Comment: Also you're stepping forward through the rows - if you delete row 2 then row 3 becomes the new row 2 and doesn't get checked in your loop as it's already checked row 2.... work from the bottom row backwards if you're going to be deleting rows as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is use a temporary sheet, copy your first column into the new sheet, remove duplicates, use a `SUMIF` formula and then copy it all back again.

```
Sub Test()

    Combine ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D14")
    'Or
    'Combine Selection

End Sub


Sub Combine(Target As Range)

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim x As Long

    'Add the temporary sheet & copy column 1 of the data over.
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Target.Columns(1).Copy Destination:=wrkSht.Columns(1)

    With wrkSht
        'Remove the duplicates from copied data and find where the last row number.
        .Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'Add a SUMIF formula to each column to calculate the totals.
        'NB: It should be possible to add the formula to all cells in one hit,
        '    but didn't have time to figure it out.
        '    The formula in column B is:
        '    =SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$14, $A1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$14)
        For x = 2 To 4
            .Range(.Cells(1, x), .Cells(lLastRow, x)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('" & Target.Parent.Name & "'!" & Target.Columns(1).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & _
                ", RC1,'" & Target.Parent.Name & "'!" & Target.Columns(x).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ")"
        Next x

        'Replace the formula with values,
        'clear the original table and copy the values back
        'to the original sheet.
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lLastRow, 4))
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Target.ClearContents
            .Copy Destination:=Target
        End With

    End With

    'Delete the temporary sheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wrkSht.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Another way is to use a pivot table.

- Create a named range that references your data.
  Using the formula below the range will increase/decrease as the list size changes:
  `=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))`
- Insert a *PivotTable* with the *Table/Range* set as `=RawData` (where your named range is `RawData`).
- Use the first column as *Row Labels*.
- Use the other columns as three sets of *Values*.
- If the raw data changes just refresh the pivot table.